# Battery level widget does not update

Tags: java, android, widget

I need to show the battery level automatically in the widget, I've tried so many solutions to resolve this issue but unfortunately the widget does not update.

Here is my code:

**Manifest.xml**

> ```
>     <receiver
>         android:name=".BatteryWidget"
>         android:label="@string/app_name">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
>             <action android:name="com.leenah.battery.action.UPDATE" />
>             <action android:name="Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
>         </intent-filter>
>
>         <meta-data
>             android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
>             android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
>     </receiver>
>
>     <service android:name=".ScreenMonitorService"></service>    </manifest>
> ```

**BatteryWidget.java**

```
public class BatteryWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static

final String ACTION_BATTERY_UPDATE = "com.leenah.battery.action.UPDATE";
private int batteryLevel = 0;

public static void turnAlarmOnOff(Context context, boolean turnOn) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BATTERY_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    if (turnOn) { // Add extra 1 sec because sometimes ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is called after the first alarm           alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 300 * 1000, pendingIntent);          LogFile.log("Alarm set");       } else {            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);             LogFile.log("Alarm disabled");      }   }

        @Override public void onEnabled (Context context){
            super.onEnabled(context);

            LogFile.log("onEnabled()");

            turnAlarmOnOff(context, true); //       context.startService(new Intent(context, ScreenMonitorService.class));      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {           context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, ScreenMonitorService.class));        } else {            context.startService(new Intent(context, ScreenMonitorService.class));      }

            //

        }

        @Override public void onUpdate (Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds){
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

            LogFile.log("onUpdate()");

            // Sometimes when the phone is booting, onUpdate method gets called before onEnabled()      int currentLevel = calculateBatteryLevel(context);      if (batteryChanged(currentLevel)) {             batteryLevel = currentLevel;            LogFile.log("Battery changed");         }


            updateViews(context);

        }

        private boolean batteryChanged ( int currentLevelLeft){

            return (batteryLevel != currentLevelLeft);
        }

        @Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
            LogFile.log("onReceive() " + intent.getAction());
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_BATTERY_UPDATE)) {
                int currentLevel = calculateBatteryLevel(context);
                if (batteryChanged(currentLevel)) {
                    LogFile.log("Battery changed");
                    batteryLevel = currentLevel;
                    updateViews(context);
                }
            }        ///


        }

        @Override public void onDisabled (Context context){
            super.onDisabled(context);

            LogFile.log("onDisabled()");

            turnAlarmOnOff(context, false);
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, ScreenMonitorService.class));
        }

        private int calculateBatteryLevel (Context context){
            LogFile.log("calculateBatteryLevel()");

            Intent batteryIntent = context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

            int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
            int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
            return level * 100 / scale;
        }

        private void updateViews (Context context){
            LogFile.log("updateViews()");
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.batteryText, batteryLevel + " %");

            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, BatteryWidget.class);
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, views);

            ////////////////

            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.batteryText);
        }

    }
```

**ScreenMonitorService.java**

> ```
> public class ScreenMonitorService extends Service {
> private static BroadcastReceiver screenOffReceiver;
> private static BroadcastReceiver screenOnReceiver;
> private static BroadcastReceiver userPresentReceiver;
>
> @Override
> public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
>     return null;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>
>     registerScreenOffReceiver();
>     registerScreenOnReceiver();
>     registerUserPresentReceiver();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onDestroy() {
>     super.onDestroy();
>
>     unregisterReceiver(screenOffReceiver);
>     unregisterReceiver(screenOnReceiver);
>     unregisterReceiver(userPresentReceiver);
> }
>
> private void registerScreenOffReceiver() {
>     screenOffReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>             LogFile.log(intent.getAction());
>             BatteryWidget.turnAlarmOnOff(context, false);
>         }
>
>     };
>
>     registerReceiver(screenOffReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
> }
>
> private void registerScreenOnReceiver() {
>     screenOnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>             LogFile.log(intent.getAction());
>
>             KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
>             if (!keyguardManager.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode())
>                 BatteryWidget.turnAlarmOnOff(context, true);
>         }
>
>     };
>
>     registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
> }
>
> private void registerUserPresentReceiver() {
>     userPresentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>             LogFile.log(intent.getAction());
>
>             BatteryWidget.turnAlarmOnOff(context, true);
>         }
>
>     };
>
>     registerReceiver(userPresentReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT));
> }
>
>   }
> ```

so the widget is showing correctly only at the first time and does not updating anymore.

Please help me to fix this problem I will be waiting for your answers.
Have a great day

Comment: Your alarm `Intent` is not going to work on Oreo and above, as implicit `Intent`s no longer work for manifest-registered Receivers. You should always be using an explicit `Intent`, anyway – e.g., `new Intent(context, BatteryWidget.class).setAction(ACTION_BATTERY_UPDATE)` – and if you're testing on Oreo or up, looking for that broadcast, that's likely why it's not seeming to work for you. Beyond that, it's hard to tell exactly what your code is, because several code lines appear to have been unintentionally merged into comment lines in the posted code.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much!
I've used the explicit intent as your example and it works correctly.
Kindly add your answer in order to accept it.